# How do I disable horizontal scrollbar in jScrollPane (JQuery)?

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

Can you guys please let me know what is the best way to disable the horiontal scroll bar?

I have div with `width: 100%` and `height :280px`. When we have long continuous text (without any spaces), we are getting a horizontal scrollbar displayed.

Btw I am using jscrollPane.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

What I have found in **jScrollPane - settings object documentation**:

> contentWidth - int (default undefined)
>
> The width of the content of the scroll pane. The default value of
>   undefined will allow jScrollPane to calculate the width of it's
>   content. However, in some cases you will want to disable this (e.g. to
>   prevent horizontal scrolling or where the calculation of the size of
>   the content doesn't return reliable results)

So to get rid of horizontal bars, just set content width lower than the container width.

Example:

```
$('#element').jScrollPane({
    contentWidth: '0px'
});
```

Comment: This does something weird with the jScrollPane and makes the width unpredictable.  (Didn't dig into it much, but tried the `horizontalDragMaxWidth: 0` trick and it worked more predictably.

Comment: `horizontalDragMaxWidth: 0` did not worked but `contentWidth: '0px' ` worked for me. Thanks for sharing.. Up Vote for this.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has so many upvotes but setting `contentWidth: '0px'` removes verticall scroll bar as well and makes the plugin unusable...

Answer (score 9):

The answer from *Sławek Wala* (`contentWidth: '0px'`) is a really magic wand :)

In IE8 unnecessary horisontal scrollbar appears often upon elastic containers. But that's only part of the trouble: when horisontal scrollbar appears *the content overflows through both vertical gutter and scrollbar*.
So, if one disables horisontal scrollbar just making it invisible (as the other answers suggest) then the second part of the trouble remains.

`contentWidth: '0px'` fixes the both symptoms.

However, *knowncitizen* was right, '0px' does something weird with the jScrollPane because contentWidth is an *integer* property (btw `contentWidth: 'foo'` gives us the same pretty result ).
To avoid unpredictable effects one can use any positive but small enough number like this: `contentWidth: 1`

Answer (score 6):

This is quite outdated question. But in case someone has same issue as you and I:

as I haven't found any property or API call to achieve this, I used simple solution - disabled via CSS:

`.jspHorizontalBar { display: none !important; }`

Not very elegant way, but saved time of investigating or 'hacking' jScrollPane code.

Comment: +1 Same here, its mad that this plugin doesn't have a simple option to force only vertical scrolling. Or I would of thought that it would of read the overflow-x/y property.

Comment: This would hide the scrollbar but also make in impossible to see the content outside the visible area!

Answer (score 3):

Pass `horizontalDragMaxWidth: 0` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me here so here's what I did using nested divs:

JS

```
$('#scrollpane').jScrollPane();
```

HTML

```
<div id="scrollpane" style="max-height: 400px; width: 700px">
    <div style="overflow:hidden; width: 650px">
        Your long content will be clipped after 650px
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this using CSS.

Since the parent should have the class `horizontal-only`, when we only want a horizontal bar, I added the class `jspVerticalBar` as a child so that when it appears ONLY under the `horizontal-only` class, it will not display it.
It will still work if you have set the vertical and horizontal on the same page.

```
div.horizontal-only .jspVerticalBar { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying and failing with the other answers, we had to hack jScrollPane to make this work. In jquery.jscrollpane.js, line 171:

```
    pane.css('overflow', 'auto');
    // Hack: Combat size weirdness with long unbreakable lines.
    pane.css('position', 'static');
    // End hack
    if (s.contentWidth) {
            contentWidth = s.contentWidth;
    } else {
            contentWidth = pane[0].scrollWidth;
    }
    contentHeight = pane[0].scrollHeight;
    // Hack: Continued.
    pane.css('position', 'absolute');
    // End hack
    pane.css('overflow', '');
```

Not sure how safe it is but that works for us.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution was in to add `left: 0 !important;` for classes `.customSelect` and `.jspPane` in the CSS:

```css
.customSelect .jspPane {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 left: 0 !important;
}
```